# get data with attr from modal window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a modal window for uploading files, it is used in this piece of code

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Photos</label>
    <div class="field_info" data-field_photo_id="5">
        <div class="value" data-item_id=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field_form">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-md btnUpload" data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#modal-upload">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
        </a>
        <div class="dz_params_item"
          data-entity_id="<?=$item->request_id?>"
          data-action_url="/files/upload/<?=$item->request_id?>"
        ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The window itself is a little lower on the page

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-upload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    ....
</div>
```

To open it and upload files, I use javascript

I have shortened the code a little everywhere so that there is no confusion, but if something is missing, then I will add

```
(function( $ ){
    $.dispatcherFiles = {
        $filesDropzone: null,
        $parallelUploads: 100,
        $maxFiles: 10,
        $modalId: '#modal-upload',
        $files: [],

        cacheDom: function(){
            this.$body = $('body');
        },

        functions: {
            openUploadFilesModal: function (e) {
                let that = this;

                let dropzoneParamEl = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.field_form').find('.dz_params_item');
                let action_url = $(dropzoneParamEl).attr('data-action_url');          

                $(this.$modalId + ' #filesDropzone').addClass('dropzone');

                this.$filesDropzone = new Dropzone(that.$modalId + ' .dropzone', {
                    url: action_url,
                    uploadMultiple: true,
                    parallelUploads: that.$parallelUploads,
                    maxFiles: that.$maxFiles,
                });
            },

            hideUploadFilesModal: function (e) {
                this.$filesDropzone.destroy();
            },
        },

        events: function(){
            this.$body.on('shown.bs.modal', this.$modalId, this.functions.openUploadFilesModal.bind(this));
            this.$body.on('hidden.bs.modal', this.$modalId, this.functions.hideUploadFilesModal.bind(this));
        },

        init: function () {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.events();
        }
    };

    $.dispatcherFiles.init();

})(jQuery);
```

So, in this example, the main problem I have is to get `data-action_url` from the html page

I am trying to do it with these lines

```
let dropzoneParamEl = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.field_form').find('.dz_params_item');
let action_url = $(dropzoneParamEl).attr('data-action_url');
```

But in the end my variable is `undefined`, even though the previous variable `dropzoneParamEl` is defined and I get the DOM of that element

And this is all just because my function is triggered when the window is opened `shown.bs.modal`

If I receive data via `click`, then I can get the attribute I need

But as far as I understand, I can’t use the `click` modal for opening, because then nothing will work at all

How can I get the value of `data-action_url` when opening the modal in this case? I’ll clarify right away that I can have several such upload buttons, and I need the value of exactly the element that was clicked

=====================================

**Update**

That is, I can simply replace two functions in events with this one

```
events: function(){
            this.$body.on('click', '#foo', this.functions.uploadFilesModal.bind(this));
        },
```

And then do everything I need to do there?

```
functions: {
            uploadFilesModal: function (e) {
                $($modalId).modal('toggle');

                let that = this;

                let dropzoneParamEl = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.field_form').find('.dz_params_item');
                let action_url = $(dropzoneParamEl).attr('data-action_url');
                
                console.log(dropzoneParamEl);
                console.log(action_url);

                ...
            },
        },
```

=====================================

I tried to make an approximate snippet, but unfortunately nothing opens ..

```js
(function($){
    let $modalId = '#modal-upload';
    let $filesDropzone = null;
    let $parallelUploads = 100;
    let $maxFiles = 10;
    let $files = [];
        
    $.dispatcherFiles = {

        cacheDom: function(){
            this.$body = $('body');
        },

        functions: {
            uploadFilesModal: function (e) {
                $($modalId).modal('toggle');
                
                let that = this;

                let dropzoneParamEl = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.field_form').find('.dz_params_item');
                let action_url = $(dropzoneParamEl).attr('data-action_url');
                
                console.log(dropzoneParamEl);
                console.log(action_url);

                $($modalId + ' #filesDropzone').addClass('dropzone');

                $filesDropzone = new Dropzone($modalId + ' .dropzone', {
                    url: action_url,
                    uploadMultiple: true,
                    parallelUploads: $parallelUploads,
                    maxFiles: $maxFiles,
                });
                
                $filesDropzone.on('error', function() {
                    $(that.$modalId).modal('hide');
                    alert('error');
                });
                
                $filesDropzone.on('success', function(file, response) {
                    $($modalId).modal('hide');
                });
            },
        },

        events: function(){
            this.$body.on('click', '.btnUpload', this.functions.uploadFilesModal.bind(this));
        },

        init: function () {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.events();
        }
    };

    $.dispatcherFiles.init();

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.field {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" 
  rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
      <label>Photos</label>
      <div class="field_info" data-field_photo_id="5">
          <div class="value" data-item_id=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="field_form">
          <a class="btn btn-dark btn-md btnUpload" data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#modal-upload">
              <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
          </a>
          <div class="dz_params_item"
            data-entity_id="<?=$item->request_id?>"
            data-action_url="/files/upload/<?=$item->request_id?>"
          ></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
      <label>Photos</label>
      <div class="field_info" data-field_photo_id="6">
          <div class="value" data-item_id=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="field_form">
          <a class="btn btn-dark btn-md btnUpload" data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#modal-upload">
              <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
          </a>
          <div class="dz_params_item"
            data-entity_id="<?=$item->request_id?>"
            data-action_url="/files/upload/<?=$item->request_id?>"
          ></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
      <label>Photos</label>
      <div class="field_info" data-field_photo_id="7">
          <div class="value" data-item_id=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="field_form">
          <a class="btn btn-dark btn-md btnUpload" data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#modal-upload">
              <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
          </a>
          <div class="dz_params_item"
            data-entity_id="<?=$item->request_id?>"
            data-action_url="/files/upload/<?=$item->request_id?>"
          ></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-upload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    Upload files
                </h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fal fa-times"></i></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="filesDropzone"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-3dZ9wIrMMij8rOH7X3kLfXAzwtcHpuYpEgQg1OA4QAob1e81H8ntUQmQm3pBudqIoySO5j0tHN4ENzA6+n2r4w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.3/dropzone.min.js" integrity="sha512-U2WE1ktpMTuRBPoCFDzomoIorbOyUv0sP8B+INA3EzNAhehbzED1rOJg6bCqPf/Tuposxb5ja/MAUnC8THSbLQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `$($modalId).modal('toggle');`, see the snippet below:

```js
(function($){
    let $modalId = '#modal-upload';
    let $filesDropzone = null;
    let $parallelUploads = 100;
    let $maxFiles = 10;
    let $files = [];
    

    $("#foo").click(function() {
        $($modalId).modal('toggle');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.field {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" 
  rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>

<div class="field">
    <label>Photos</label>
    <div class="field_info" data-field_photo_id="5">
        <div class="value" data-item_id=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field_form">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-md btnUpload" data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#modal-upload" id="foo">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
        </a>
        <div class="dz_params_item"
          data-entity_id="<?=$item->request_id?>"
          data-action_url="/files/upload/<?=$item->request_id?>"
        ></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-upload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    Upload files
                </h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fal fa-times"></i></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="filesDropzone"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-3dZ9wIrMMij8rOH7X3kLfXAzwtcHpuYpEgQg1OA4QAob1e81H8ntUQmQm3pBudqIoySO5j0tHN4ENzA6+n2r4w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: wrote a small comment before the snippet, please have a look

Comment: I also updated my snippet and it seems that now I get the value I need, now I'll try to check all this in more detail on my own

Comment: This is not visible on the snippet, but I have a problem, this window opens and literally closes in half a second

Comment: @Hector if it reproduces in your project, but not in the snippet, then it's highly probable that you have some Javascript code that periodically does something you do not need. Maybe you could search for `setInterval` in your code, that's a good way to try and find the problem you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you *can* use `on("click")` together with the built-in into HTML tag `dialog`. Consider its [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog).

Here's a short example without any styling. Hope it works. If the user cancels the "choose file" dialog window, the HTML dialog closes automatically, too.

```js
$("#show").on("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("upload").showModal();
});

$("#upload").on("close", function() {
  if (this.returnValue === "cancel") {
    // User canceled the dialog
  } else if (this.returnValue === "submit") {
    var file = document.getElementById("file").files;
    // User submitted the dialog
    // Use the "item" method to retrieve File objects
    
    var target = $("#show").closest(".field_form").find(".dz_params_item");
    var url = target.attr("data-action_url");
    
    // What you do with "data-action_url"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<dialog id="upload">
  <form>
    <!-- Add a style if you want -->
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <!-- Anything else you'd like to be near the file input -->
    <br /><br />
    <div>
      <!-- Again, here might be a class or something -->
      <button value="cancel" formmethod="dialog">Cancel</button>
      <button value="submit" formmethod="dialog">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</dialog>

<button id="show">Upload</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the instance of the DOM object or jQuery Object doing this

```js
let dropzoneParamEl = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.field_form').find('.dz_params_item');
```

I mean, the dropzoneParamEl has the DOM you need, then use this code:

```js
let action_url = $(dropzoneParamEl).data('action_url');
```

I have been using that function for long time with jQuery.

Also is possible to see the 'data' attributes using vanilla javascript, using:

```
let dropzoneParamEl = document.querySelector('.dz_params_item');

dropzoneParamEl.dataset.action_url
```

You must change code to fit your need, but basically you get data using those 2 options